# How can I use a ChromiumWebBrowser when Collapsed

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I have a `ChromiumWebBrowser` control with `Visibility` of `Collapsed`.  Until the visibility is set to `Visible`, the page is not loaded and many calls fail with:

> `System.Exception`: The browser has not been initialized. `Load` can only be called after the underlying CEF browser is initialized (`CefLifeSpanHandler::OnAfterCreated`).

How can I have the page be loaded when the `Visibility` is `Collapsed`?

Comment: Have you considered just setting  the control's height or width to zero rather than collapsing it?

Comment: @Andy, `ChromiumWebBrowser` doesn't seem to actually care about `Visibility` - it is just waiting for a non-zero `ActualSize`.  I'm not sure what would happen with one non-zero dimension, but I still think the explicit `CreateOffscreenBrowser` call is more reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subclass of `ChromiumWebBrowser` as described in [Render problems when Initial Visibility Collapsed](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1412).  To work around a `NullReferenceException` in `AbstractRenderHandler.OnPaint`, you will need to ensure the visual tree is already created (by calling `ApplyTemplate`).

Example:

```
internal sealed class CollapsableChromiumWebBrowser : ChromiumWebBrowser
{
    public CollapsableChromiumWebBrowser()
    {
        this.Loaded += this.CollapsableChromiumWebBrowser_Loaded;
    }

    private void CollapsableChromiumWebBrowser_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Avoid loading CEF in designer
        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        {
            return;
        }

        // Avoid NRE in AbstractRenderHandler.OnPaint
        ApplyTemplate();
        // https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1412
        CreateOffscreenBrowser(new Size(400, 400));
    }
}
```